# jsf user html input security

Tags: security, jsf, html-parsing, wysiwyg

in my application i have some tinymce editors and the userinput is shown with

```
<h:outputText escape="false"/>
```

but how can i prevent malicious input, like javascript or iframes? Is there any lib which can filter the input strings?

UPDATE:
i found "htmlpurifier" but it is for php, is there anyting like this for java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a HTML parser which supports cleaning/whitelisting tags/attributes. Among them there's [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org), it has a `clean()` method for exactly this purpose. Here's an extract of relevance from [its site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

> ### [Sanitize untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)
>
> #### Problem
>
> You want to allow untrusted users to supply HTML for output on your website (e.g. as comment submission). You need to clean this HTML to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks.
>
> #### Solution
>
> Use the jsoup HTML [`Cleaner`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html) with a configuration specified by a [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).
>
> ```
> String unsafe = 
>       "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
> String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
>       // now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
> ```